# Como fazer ativador de pincode via serial?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jdbc

Estou tentando fazer validador de pincode (serial), mas não sei como fazer.

Tenho duas tabelas: "validacao" e "vencimento".

Na tabela "validacao", tem os seguintes campos:

```
id(int), data(varchar), pincode(varchar), status(int)
```

Na tabela "vencimento", tem os seguintes campos:

```
id(int), data(varchar)
```

As datas estão formatadas como "*ddmmaaaa*". Ou seja, uma data como "17/11/2016" fica "17112016".

O meu código está assim:

```
public void Valida(String senha) {
    conex.conexao();
    conex.executaSql("select * from vencimento");
    try {
        conex.rs.last();
        valida = Integer.parseInt(conex.rs.getString("data"));
        int operacao = (valida + 132) / 4;
        int senhaValidacao = Integer.parseInt(senha);
        if (operacao == senhaValidacao) {
            int dia, mes, ano;
            String AcertaMes, AcertaDia, ProxSenha;
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date hoje = new Date();
            String data = df.format(hoje);
            char[] senhachar = data.toCharArray();
            dia = Integer.parseInt("" + senhachar[0] + senhachar[1]);
            mes = Integer.parseInt("" + senhachar[3] + senhachar[4]);
            ano = Integer.parseInt("" + senhachar[6] + senhachar[7] + senhachar[8] + senhachar[9]);

            if (mes < 12) {
                mes++;
                if(mes<10){
                    AcertaMes = "0"+mes;
                }
                else{
                    AcertaMes = ""+mes;
                }
            } else {
                mes = 1;
                ano++;
                AcertaMes = "0"+mes;
            }
            if(dia<10){
                AcertaDia = "0"+dia;

            }else{
                AcertaDia = ""+dia;
            }
            ProxSenha = AcertaDia+AcertaMes+ano;
            PreparedStatement pst = conex.con.prepareStatement("insert into vencimento (data)values(?)");
            pst.setString(1, ProxSenha);
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sistema valido ate: "+dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano+" Entre novamente!");

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PINCODE INCORRETO VERIFIQUE OU ENTRE EM COTATO COM A ADVANCE SISTEMAS");
        }
        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, valida);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao Validar" + ex);
    }
```

Eis a ideia do código:

- Toda vez que chegar a data de validar, o sistema irá gerar um pincode e um status da próxima data de vencimento, que verifica que  se já foi ativo ou não na tabela "validacao".
- Quando o usuário ou cliente digitar o pincode, irá fazer um "*update*" na tabela "vencimento" puxando a data da "validacao", e fazendo um "*update*" na tabela "validacao", no campo "status", mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

Comment: É essencial fazer um texto o mais claro possível, ao relatar o problema, o seu estava extremamente confuso, o que dificulta o entendimento. Fiz algumas edições pra melhoria no texto, para facilitar a compreensão, verifique se está condizente com o problema. E no mais, tem que ter um pouco de paciência mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado ! amigo !

Comment: Lembre-se que dos "tantos usuários", boa parte é trazendo dúvidas, e não respostas. Além disso, conforme o @diegofm comentou, seria melhor [edit] e explicar o que é pro código fazer, e qual a dificuldade (ou o que deu de errado). Pode ter acontecido das pessoas terem lido sua pergunta e não terem entendido a dúvida. Eu, por exemplo, não faço idéia do que você entende por pincode e pincode validado. Se é só uma senha de 4 digitos, por exemplo, ou se tem alguma regra especial. Além disso, não dá pra saber se dá erro, se só não localiza, etc, melhor você explicar. Veja umas dicas: [ask].

Comment: vamos ver se agora o pessoal ira me ajudar

Comment: Melhorou bastante. Agora só tenha paciência, lembre-se que o site é colaborativo, ou seja, ninguém recebe pra responder, todos ajudam por boa vontade e desejo de compartilhar conhecimento. Uma hora alguém acaba te respondendo. ;)

Comment: Se para cada validação houver um único vencimento e para cada vencimento houver uma única validação, então você poderia colocar os dois em uma tabela só e ficaria muito mais simples e fácil. Por outro lado, se uma validação puder ter vários vencimentos, então você não tem nenhuma chave estrangeira para relacionar os dois e daí, você teria que acrescentar uma.

Comment: Revisei o seu texto e reacrescentei o código que você havia removido da pergunta. Do jeito que estava, eu não conseguia entender o que você queria perguntar.

Comment: Você pode colocar o código da classe referente à variável `conex`?

Comment: Ola boa tarde agora estou na serviço, quando chegar em casa voce me ajuda ? obrigado !

Comment: teria como de me ajudar Victor ?